# Show a submit button on table row mouseover

Tags: php, javascript, html

First of all, forgive me for being a beginner to Javascript and PHP.

Second:
I have a table with some order information, and the first cell of every row consists of a submit button that will send the information from that row to a second page where it will be displayed.

I wrote a small Javascript function so that the submit buttons are hidden until someone mouses over them. But my problem is that the submit ID for the buttons is assigned to the first button, so no matter what row I mouse over, only the first submit button displays.

The display function is the following:

```
    function showButton(id) 
    {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
           e.style.display = 'none';
        else
           e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

The row is defined as:

```
    tr onmouseover='showButton("submitButton");'
                   onmouseout='showButton("submitButton");'>
```

And the button which is generated on every iteration of a new row is:

```
    input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Submit' 
                   style='cursor: pointer; display: none;' />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I want the correct submit button appearing next to each row on mouseover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be easily accomplished with just CSS, like this:

```css
tr input { display: none; }
tr:hover input { display: inline; }
```

Comment: IE doesn't handle :hover for anything but anchors, if I recall correctly.. The way he's doing it is the more preferred way for the cross-browser support.

Comment: @DanRedux, I think it's supported in IE7+ (in strict mode)

Comment: @DanRedux Why? I guess deciding on `display` versus `visibility` really depends on other factors (how the table is styled, what else is in the same cell along with the `<input>`, etc.). And the OP already used `display` on his code. As for IE6, I believe the standard behavior today is dropping support for it (even Microsoft doesn't support it anymore!). If the client requires that, I strongly advise charging extra for the coding nightmare! :)

Comment: Worked perfectly. IE6 support is not needed. And if it is, I'm already using :hover for other things, so that's out the window.

Comment: Hahahah, good for you then npiani, we're all trying to get IE6 to pack up and leave, but for some of us we HAVE to support it, or lose a client and lose loads of money. >_<

Comment: Yeah I understand. this is just an in-house tool for our small company. So if we really have to we can have two or people not use IE6.